# Can I force dhclient to use the client identifier from /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: 12.04, networking, dhcp, dhclient

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with isc dhclient version 4.1.

My goal is to use DHCP to get IP addresses for multiple sub-interfaces on eth0.  I have three stanzas configured for that in my `/etc/network/interfaces` file.  And I can get it to work if I specify the `hwaddress` option to be different for each interface.  However I would prefer to use the client option rather than change the MAC address.  The problem is `dhclient` isn't sending the client-identifier when I specify the client option in `/etc/network/interfaces`.  I captured the DHCP traffic on `ifup` and verified that the client-identifier was not being sent.

Is there a way (maybe in dhclient.conf?) to have dhclient get the client-identifier from the interfaces file and actually send it in the DHCP request when `ifup` is called?  Or is there a better way to do this altogether?

Here's an example of my interfaces file attempting to use the client option:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
  client testiface0

auto eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet dhcp
  client testiface1

auto eth0:3
iface eth0:3 inet dhcp
  client testiface2
```

My dhclient.conf file has this line in it: `send host-name "<hostname>";`   If there's an equivalent for client-identifier, I think that would work but I couldn't find anything about it in the man pages.